# AccessTokenLifeTime expiration- Identity server code flow

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

I have an ASP.NET Core application with IdentityServer4 for authentication and authorization.
I am using oidc-client with Angular 10 for the front-end.
The problem is my application never logs the user out even after the token is expired. it will be refreshed silently.
My AccessTokenLifetime is set to 5 minutes.
My CookieSlidingTime is set to 10 minute.
Here is my code

```
    const idServerSettings = {
  authority: Constants.stsAuthority,
  client_id: Constants.clientId,
  scope: 'openid profile',
  response_type: 'code',
  redirect_uri: `${Constants.clientRoot}signin-callback`,
  post_logout_redirect_uri: `${Constants.clientRoot}signout-callback`,
  store: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: localStorage }),
  automaticSilentRenew: true,
  loadUserInfo: true
};
```

IdentityServer configuration

```
 new Client {
                ClientName="test",
                ClientId="client-spa",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code,
                AlwaysIncludeUserClaimsInIdToken = true,
                RedirectUris = new List<string>() { "https://localhost:44383/signin-callback" }, 
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = {"https://localhost:44383/signout-callback" },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = {  "https://localhost:44383" },
                AccessTokenLifetime = 60*5, // TODO
                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "propel-api"

                },
                RequireClientSecret=false
            }



   var builder = services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
        {
            options.Events.RaiseErrorEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseInformationEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseFailureEvents = true;
            options.Events.RaiseSuccessEvents = true;
            options.UserInteraction.LoginUrl = "/Account/Login";
            options.UserInteraction.LogoutUrl = "/Account/Logout";
            options.Authentication = new AuthenticationOptions()
            {
                CookieLifetime = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), 
                CookieSlidingExpiration = true,
                
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silent refresh is because you have `automaticSilentRenew` set to true, per [docs](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/wiki):

> automaticSilentRenew (boolean, default: false): Flag to indicate if there should be an automatic attempt to renew the access token prior to its expiration. The attempt is made as a result of the accessTokenExpiring event being raised.

- If you are looking for an automatic logout, that is not there by design, you need to implement the sign out. [Ref](https://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/topics/signout.html#sign-out).
- To force user to re-login after some time of inactivity, there is no out of the box solution available on `oidc-client-js` ([Ref](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/530#issuecomment-380622994)) . What you can do is to:

  1. Set `automaticSilentRenew` to false
  2. Implement your own logic to indicate user inactivity and call [signinSilent API](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/blob/dev/src/UserManager.js#L160) manually. [Ref](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js/issues/530#issuecomment-380536762)

     Here is some examples for this approach: [IdS4 sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57607178/log-out-user-when-idle-using-identityserver4-oidc-client-js-in-angular), [Okta sample](https://medium.com/@yau.yik.shiung/oidc-idle-timeout-design-5149da2be93e)
- If you want to force user to re-login after some time:

  1. Set `automaticSilentRenew` = false
  2. Set `UserSsoLifetime` for the client on IDS4 configuration. [Ref](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/client.html?highlight=UserSsoLifetime#authentication-logout)

  > UserSsoLifetime: The maximum duration (in seconds) since the last time the user authenticated. Defaults to null. You can adjust the lifetime of a session token to control when and how often a user is required to reenter credentials instead of being silently authenticated, when using a web application.

  For example `UserSsoLifetime = 10` will force the user to re-authenticate after 10 s of inactivity.

Comment: thanks, when I use UserSsoLifetime = 30 it will log me out even when I am using the application. What I am trying to achieve is being logged out after 30 seconds of **inactivity**. now when I have the accesstokelifetime = 30, I will close the browser for ten minutes and access the application again, it will redirect me to signcallback and authenticate me without redirecting me to identityserver log in page.